# Changing identifier type

Tags: c++

I'm working on a hack and made an overlay with DirectX however now that I have implemented it my functions are throwing errors. I looked into it and it is changing their identifier type.

```
DWORD GetProcID(const wchar_t* procName){

DWORD procId = 0;
HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

    if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
    {
        do
        {
            if (!_wcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
            {
                procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));

    }
}
CloseHandle(hSnap);
return procId;}
```

That is one of the functions I am using. In my console app, it works fine but when I put it in my windows app(the DirectX overlay) it changes PROCESSENTRY32 to green and throws an error

In the console app it looks like this

[image: snapshot of code snippet]

and the definition for the identifier is

[image: snapshot of code snippet]

But in the Windows app, it looks like this

[image: snapshot of code snippet]

I'm new to c++ and I don't really know how to explain it but any help would be nice

Comment: What is the error? Are both projects set to the same character set?

Comment: Error (active) E0167 argument of type "CHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *" and what do you mean by character set. everything is copy pasted from the console app to the win app

Comment: It looks like @RetiredNinja was on the money here.  Indeed, there is a character type mismatch.  It sounds like you're passing a `char*` to this function, but the project is configured to use wide characters.  Welcome to Windows programming...  What line of code is the error on?  Do we have to painstakingly drag all the useful information out of you one piece at a time?  Please just share actual detail.

Comment: Use the `W` versions of functions and structs explicitly since you use `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Jeez @paddy no need to be so mean i said i was new and thanks ted that worked

Comment: Righto, sorry for the Frustration Overflow.

Comment: Please, don't include code snippets as images. Instead, copy/paste them as text. (This is required according to the guidelines in [ask]: _**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**_)